# Property is accessed but result is unused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I saw there another similar one to my question but that was very old! , So I have an UIActivityIndicatorView but when i try to call the .hidesWhenStopped it just warns Property is accessed but result is unused for no reason?

What could be the problem?
I tried under viewDidLoad too but same :(

This is a part of my code:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { [self] _ in
   monitorimiTableView.reloadData()
   configureTableView()
   loaderMonitorimi.hidesWhenStopped // Property is accessed but result is unused
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a value to the property:

```
loaderMonitorimi.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

(or `false` if you don't want to hide it)

If you just write `loaderMonitorimi.hidesWhenStopped` without any assignment, this expression will result in the boolean value stored in the `hidesWhenStopped` property, but the result of the expression is not used, hence the warning.

Comment: Worked as a charm!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! , learned something new and useful.

Comment: @ioslifer, Were you trying to set your UIActivityIndicatorView so that it hides when stopped?

Comment: @DuncanC yep excactly

Comment: If you search in the Xcode docs on "hidesWhenStopped", you can find it in the docs for UIActivityIndicatorView. It says the property is a boolean with a getter and a setter. That means you can read the value from it, or assign a new value to it. If you just say `loaderMonitorimi.hidesWhenStopped`, you are reading the current value of that flag, but not doing anything with the result. If you wrote `print(loaderMonitorimi.hidesWhenStopped)` it would print `true` or `false` to the console.